# Django saving HTTP_REFERER to use it as landingpage information

Tags: python, django, cookies, http-headers, http-referer

I would like to know if there is a better solution for this.

The website I'm building has some forms which need information about the page the user started his 'journy'. Right now I'm saving HTTP_REFERER to the session and use it later on. 
A disadvantage is the need for set_expiry(0) which clears the session on browser close. I like the behavior that users don't need to login every time they close the browser.

I wrote a little middleware class that looks like this:

```
class RefererMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        try:
            if not request.session.get('http_landingpage'):
                request.session['http_landingpage'] = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
                request.session.set_expiry(0)
        except Exception:
            pass
        return response
```

Any suggestions for improvement? Other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [setting a cookie](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie), which will expire when the browser is closed. You can do it in the middleware and in the end the session will be left intact.

```
#Usage: response.set_cookie( 'cookie_name', 'cookie_value' )

class RefererMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if not request.COOKIES.has_key( 'HTTP_REFERER' ):
            response.set_cookie( 'HTTP_REFERER', request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') )
        return response
```